# sql выбрать максимальное из трех столбцов ( mysql )

Tags: sql

В результате `join` запроса получилась таблица такого вида:

```
id,date1,date2,date3
```

необходимо привести к виду

```
id, max(date1,date2,date3)
```

`date-формат` `timestamp` и поле может быть пустым.

Пытался использовать что то вроде : `CASE WHEN a>b THEN a ELSE b END`, но запутался.

Comment: пытался использовать что то вроде : CASE WHEN a>b  THEN a ELSE b  END, но запутался

Answer (score 4):

Решение такое:

```
greatest(IFNULL(date1,0),IFNULL(date2,0),IFNULL(date3,0))
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте `greatest(coalesce(date1,0),coalesce(date2,0),coalesce(date3,0))`

С ifnull() тоже можно и вроде как бы логичней, но coalesce() определён в ansi sql, должен по идее работать с любой БД, и поэтому предпочтительней.

Comment: GREATEST() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

Comment: Да, там надо coalsece() расставить, где null всплывает